# How to use memmap kernel parameter?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel

I want to reserve 512 MB of RAM starting from 2GB. I have tried using `memmap=512M$2G`. But after restart when I used `cat /proc/cmdline`, it displays `memmap=512MM` and the system become very slow. I am using non UEFI system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This varies with grub versions and distribution, but you probably need to add escape characters:

```
memmap=512M\\\$2G
```

Comment: Is there a way to verify this is working? For example I have the command line options correct, but it's showing the same amount of available memory.

Comment: yes, `cat /proc/cmdline` will show if grub2 has interpreted `$2`. Actually it's not grub2 but the shell that interprets `$2`. That said this bug seems to have been fixed for a while now.